# How Do i get a Specific Blog Post from Blogger.com In XML format?

Tags: android, xml, web, blogger

Am working on a little project with Blogger.com.

I am Interested in getting a Specific Blog Post from Blogger.com in XML format.

I already got the List of Blog Post by using Blogger Blog Feeds

e.g https://www.blogger.com/feeds/*Blog ID*/posts/default

Please How do i get a specific Blogger.com post in XML Format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fetching a specific post, you will require its Post ID. The URL to send the request would be of the following format -

```
https://www.blogger.com/feeds/Blog ID/posts/default/Post ID
```

A live example would be -

https://www.blogger.com/feeds/596098824972435195/posts/default/3734053359418447610

These are public APIs and no authentication is required.

For the post list, you can reduce the response size by requesting only summary text by sending a request to

```
https://www.blogger.com/feeds/Blog ID/posts/summary
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of getting post title from blogger XML feed using jquery and Ajax.

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://YourBlog/feeds/posts/default',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find('entry').each(function(t) {
                $('#container').append('<div>' + $(this).find('title').text() + '</div>');
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

**But** [Blogger JSON feed](http://www.mybloggertricks.com/2015/10/introduction-to-blogger-json-feeds-and-blogger-data-api.html) is lightweight and easy to use compared to XML.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out.